# How do I adjust speed of an object in gamemaker studio 2

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

Currently, I have this in my step event.

y += sign(mouse_y - y);

I am trying to adjust how fast it goes towards the mouse so I can have it scrolling up and down the screen. sorry if this has been asked before I need an updated answer.

Comment: It has been a while since I used gamemaker studio 2 only recently I have started messing with it again.

Comment: Do mean increasing/decreasing the change by a fixed amount or do you need something more sophisticated? If you use something like `y += sign(mouse_y - y)*scale;` the speed would triple for `scale=3` or go half as fast for `scale=0.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to change the movement rate by a fixed amount you could use something like:

```
y += sign(mouse_y - y)*scale;
```

Setting the variable `scale` to 3 would triple the movement rate whereas setting it to 0.5 would halve it.

For more sophisticated changes you could modify the `scale` in your game loop or update function to gradually speed up or slow down over time.

Comment: thanks this helped me with what I needed Perhaps you could give me that sophisticated version later :D